# navigation changes by scrolling to different sections of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want my webpage navigation to work like this:
[example web page](http://www.linktechgroup.com/)

As you scroll on the page, the navigation link changes as well.

Here is how my navigation is setup:

```
 <nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li>
            <a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">

                <span class="label-nav">
                    Home
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#aboutus" class="smoothScroll">

                <span class="label-nav">
                    About Us
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#families" class="smoothScroll">

                <span class="label-nav">
                    Families
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">
                <span class="label-nav" >
                    Contact
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Smooth scrolling works on my site.  I can click on each navigation link and it animates to that section of the page by help of the smoothScroll.js

I set this to my css:

```
a.visited{
  font: #fff;
  background-color: #3498db;
}
```

Clicking my navigation works fine, but I need to get a.visted to work when i scroll to that section of the page.

Here is some code for the stickyMenu for my navigation:

```
 function stickyMenu() {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 35) {
            $('#header').addClass('sticky-header');
            $('.sticky-navigation,#to-top-button').fadeIn();

            if ($(this).scrollTop() < $('section[data-anchor="home"]').offset().top) {
                $('nav a').removeClass('active');
            }

            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('section[data-anchor="home"]').offset().top) {
                $('nav a').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
            }

            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('section[data-anchor="aboutus"]').offset().top) {
                $('nav a').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a:eq(1)').addClass('active');
            }
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('section[data-anchor="families"]').offset().top) {
                $('nav a').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a:eq(2)').addClass('active');
            }
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('section[data-anchor="contact"]').offset().top) {
                $('nav a').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a:eq(3)').addClass('active');
            }

        }
        else {
            $('#header').removeClass('sticky-header');
            $('.sticky-navigation,#to-top-button').fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

I set up each section as such, and did this for each section of the navigation:

```
<div id="content">
<section id ="about" data-anchor="about">
```

any help would be appreciate, as I am learning js and jquery as I am learning html.  Pointing me to certain files that need fixing so I can solve this would also be a great help!

Comment: Well, you're almost there. You only need to set the .visited class to the menu item who's page section is currently in the viewport. What do you not understand at this point?

Comment: @koenpeters would you be able to show that to me? Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [Scrollspy](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy), so the window will know what element is visible & can then apply the appropriate class for styling.

Comment: I downloaded the js file and put it in the approiate folder.  From what I see in the instructions I have set the script in the head to call the file.  The code is very intimidating, so what would I need to change in the js file for it to fit my file?